# increasing speed and efficiency of ajax call

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, geolocation

I'm not the most disciplined dev, dont know standards and am self-taught so bear with me. I create stuff very logically and fast but not always using 'programming standards'.

I have a mobile app using geolocation API. it gets thousands of places from my db and makes gmaps v3 markers for the ones around the user's current location.

there is an ajax call from my JS to an aspx page that calls the database, makes a json string, and sends the json string to the javascript that then creates the google map markers.

would i save time if the json string was in a flat file? im not sure if, generally speaking, accessing a sql db from an aspx page is faster than c# file i/o on a flat file with pre-rendered JSON.

EDIT: the bottle neck is in the JS not the server side code.

(of course, using the flat file, it would update everytime the db is updated)

```
function ajaxReturn(responseText) {
    var JSONbizarray = (responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf('<span id="Label1">'), responseText.indexOf('</span>')).replace('<span id="Label1">', ''));
    var JSONBizList = JSON.parse(JSONbizarray);

    var list = document.getElementById('businessListContent');
    list.innerHTML = "";
    list.innerHTML += "<ul id=\"barListUL\" data-role=\"listview\" data-theme=\"d\" data-dividertheme=\"d\">";

    for (var i = 0; i < JSONBizList.length; i++) {
        var biz = JSONBizList[i];
        list.innerHTML += "<li tabindex=\"0\" data-theme=\"d\" class=\"ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-hover-d\" role=\"option\">stuff using json object</li>";
    }

    list.innerHTML += "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: If you mean that you would have some process maintaining a "flat file" of JSON which gets updated every time the database changes, and then the ajax calls would simply return data from that file, I would think that it could speed things up, but I'm not sure that the difference would be worth it. You could try it and measure it, but is your current implementation noticeably slow, or...?

Comment: thanks @nnnnnn and yes thats exactly what I mean, and its slow (8 seconds) although the mapview seems to be faster than listview which confuses me a ton since its much more complex (mapview like 5 seconds, listview around 8)

Comment: I'd like the load time without internet connection hindrance to be more like 3-4 seconds. and these times are for ~1000 json objects with 7 attributes each.

Comment: Sounds like an extra layer of complexity you don't necessarily need and could introduce more potential points of failure. Database access shouldn't be slow unless perhaps you are using a somewhat 'bloated' framework like EF or other API? Also for the service layer you shouldn't be using an ASPX page in my opinion. Consider a WCF service or raw http interface, which should be faster. If you combine a raw SqlDataReader + raw http requests or even restful WCF it should be very fast.

Comment: whats EF, or other API's you think would slow this kind of thing down? I believe I am using a standard DB connection string through the .NET entity framework (it is MySQL instead of MSSQL but i had a addon to vs2010 that let me build entity objects from MySQL COULD THAT BE IT???), i dont know if that can be called an API or not?

Comment: wait EF is entity framework isn't it...dammit. what would i use instead? i like how it automatically creates the models for your tables...should I just use a SQLReader?

Comment: @user1048824, Yes, generally speaking Entity Framework performs slower than a raw SQLDataReader for sure. That doesn't mean you shouldn't use it ever, but if you are seeing poor performance it could be a part of the problem. It really depends on alot of factors though, so you should profile it yourself to be sure. Is your data model really complex enough to warrant using EF?

Comment: @Sean Thoman alright ill be honest: i doubt its complex enough, its 8 related tables, just my time constraints i suppose :( also whats faster about using a WCF service over a page?

Comment: @user1048824, WCF isn't necessarily the fastest approach either, but its much more convenient and designed precisely for what you are doing, and encourages a clean seperation of concerns between your database, service layer, and front-end presentation layer, etc. Theres also built in support for servicing requests for JSON and you can define contracts between the client and server.

Comment: Hey guys, the bottleneck is in the Javascript not the C#. its more than linear with size of list. (super friggin confused). gonna go through it and time stuff. thanks for hte help. even with my non-ideal server side setup it processes it super fast...its the client side JS thats being slow.

Comment: Why don't you just output HTML from your C#, rather than outputting JSON and then basically turning that into HTML on the client side. If you do keep doing it the current way, don't repeatedly use `.innerHTML += ...` - build it up in a variable and then put it in the document once at the end.

Comment: yeah i changed that. but it didnt speed up loading. it turned out being something about db access. i made it from 15 to 1 second load time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way to answer performance question except try and measure.

`Stopwatch` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx ) class will take care of measuring, and File.ReadAllLines ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx ) will provide "read from file. In about 5 lines of code and you have your answer personalized for your DB/disk/servers/network.

Answer (score 1):

Caching data locally is always a nice idea.  I'd certainly look for opportunities.  However, you would likely run into problems with the volume of data you'd need to store locally in your scenario.

Another thing to consider is working on efficiency on the server end.  Make sure the call to the server is a GET and can be cached there.

Comment: the call is a GET, how can i cache it server side?